# Is there any difference between empty block and Unit

Tags: kotlin

Is there any difference between empty block and returning Unit?

for example, we should make empty block to method do nothing

```
void ThisMethodDoesNothing() { }
```

In kotlin, we can write code above but this way

```
fun ThisMethodDoesNothing() = Unit
```

Please let me know if this is duplicated, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured that the two probably did the same thing, but I had no way to be sure.  I really wanted to know.  So I created a class to put each of these in (since Java must have a class around any code), changed the Kotlin version so that the attributes on the method were the same, and that gave me this:

a.java

```
public class a {
    public final void ThisMethodDoesNothing() { }
}
```

b.kt

```
class b {
    fun ThisMethodDoesNothing() = Unit
}
```

Then I compiled each of these, and then decompiled them with `javad -c`, and got:

```
> javap -c com.inlet.ifserver.a
Compiled from "a.java"
public class com.inlet.ifserver.a {
  public com.inlet.ifserver.a();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public final void ThisMethodDoesNothing();
    Code:
       0: return
}

> javap -c com.inlet.ifserver.b
Compiled from "b.kt"
public final class com.inlet.ifserver.b {
  public final void ThisMethodDoesNothing();
    Code:
       0: return

  public com.inlet.ifserver.b();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #11                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return
}
```

So I think the answer is a resounding YES!  Both do absolutely nothing.